# How to Index filesystems using Apache solr

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have around 18 lack document(filesystems),I have searched on intrenet there are lack of article for filesystem, please suggest me, how to do it. which method i should be used dataimport handler or solrJ ?

Comment: What is that you really want to do? Indexing 18 Lack documents for what?

Comment: Hi @prateek, I have a fielsystems which has 18 lac files and I want to index whole fielsystems using solr.I have study documentation of solr,i find the two way we can index file systms DataImporthandler or Solrj

Comment: If you have gone through solr documentation you would know that for solr document you need to have a document id. You need to understand the layout of the data and massage it to adhere to what solr needs.

Comment: thanks Prateek, I want to take suggestion for filesystems indexing dataimporthandler is the best way to do or Solrj ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at sample data configuration file at
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#FileListEntityProcessor

You need to use something like XPathEntityProcessor to define
entities for indexing. Other entity processors, such as
PlainTextEntityProcessor,
can instead be used if you are not using XML files. Also, make sure
that the field definitions in your schema.xml match the field names
here.

Comment: thanks you Godfrey, Exactly this will be needfull for my requirement

Comment: @godrey During indexing i need to use some operation like extraction columns and and make some operation like add something to it. So how i will do suck operation using DIH. If i will use SolrJ then i can do anything because i have a good knowledge of Java. Please help me out for this dificulties

Thanks in advance